# PHP ' inside " inside '

Tags: php, jquery

I have some code to display a thumbnail on hover over an image.

```
<div onmouseover="document.getElementById('logo').style.display='block';" 
     onmouseout="document.getElementById('logo').style.display='none';">
    <img src = "img.jpg"/>                                          
</div>
```

This time I want to choose the image to display instead of the static "img.jpg", which will be stored in variable $filename and then I want to append that to another jquery variable $result:

I tried this but there's confusion with single quotes:

```
$result.= '
           <div onmouseover="document.getElementById('logo').style.display='block';" 
            onmouseout="document.getElementById('logo').style.display='none';">
               <img  src = "images/' . $filename.'"/>                                         
           </div>
';
```

The confusion arises with single quotes around 'logo', 'block' and 'none'. How do I include single quotes in such situation?

Comment: Use \ to escape \' :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to escape your `'` with `\'`.

```
$result.= '
    <div onmouseover="document.getElementById(\'logo\').style.display=\'block\';" 
         onmouseout="document.getElementById(\'logo\').style.display=\'none\';">
        <img src="images/' . $filename . '"/>                                         
    </div>
';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$result.= '
       <div onmouseover="document.getElementById(\'logo\').style.display=\'block\';" 
        onmouseout="document.getElementById(\'logo\').style.display=\'none\';">
           <img  src = "images/' . $filename.'"/>                                         
       </div>
';
```